# Azure - API Management - Management API SAS token expiry

Tags: azure-api-management, sas-token

We have an API management instance in azure.We have also enabled the management API. There we have set a SAS token & that has been used in the application. Here, we have to change the SAS token in every 30 days. If the token is expired, that will result into an application outage. Is there any way to get notified via email or any other means about the token expiry (in advance). I did some research on this, but , unfortunately could not find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is built-in support for this.

You could instead have a [logic app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/) that takes in a SAS Token as input and schedules emails based on the expiry of the token.

**TIP** Apart from an email, you could do more interesting workflows like sending actionable messages using [office 365 outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/#send-approval-email) or `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/teams/#post-an-adaptive-card-to-a-teams-channel-and-wait-for-a-response` connectors and even [create a work item in Azure Devops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/visualstudioteamservices/#create-a-work-item) or [create an issue on GitHub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/github/#create-an-issue), depending on what you use.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could create Azure AD application with client id and client secret, give it permissions to do what you need to be done in APIM and use its credentials to do all the same operations via ARM.